# Magento searchbox - How to add the Searchbox on the left side of a 3columns.phtml page?

Tags: php, magento

Is it possible to add the **search box** within the **3columns.phtml** (like my categories.)

So for example i’d like to have on my products page on the left side:

So in the 3columns.phtml I have this line , the left div.

```
<div class="col-left sidebar"><?php  echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></div>
```

**So **what kind of code and where*** should I include In order that the search box appears on the left ?*

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good use for the file local.xml in your design layout folder. If you haven't created one yet, it goes:

```
/app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/layout/local.xml
```

**local.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">

    <default>

        <reference name="left">

            <block type="core/template" name="searchbox" template="path/to/searchbox.phtml" after="sibling.blockName"/>

        </reference>

    </default>

</layout>
```

Refresh your cache and that should work on all pages set to have the left column.

**Explanation**

This is one of the few methods that Magento has built in to load layout blocks. The first couple of tags are required on all layout files, `<default>` marks the update handle to apply to all pages. `<reference name="left">` means we are altering the left bar, "left" being its block name. Now lets look at the block below:

- `type="core/template"` - This type signifies which classes to use, as tied to `app/code/core/Mage/*` typically, but can be overwritten by copying the class files over to the `app/code/local/Mage/*` directory, as well as signifying classes of extensions like `app/code/community/another_extension`.
- `name="searchbox"` - This is the name it will be referenced by in the layout. You can give it something else, but make sure it doesn't conflict with existing block names.
- `template="path/to/searchbox"` - This is where you enter the path to the template file that will be loaded.
- `after="sibling.blockName"` - This marks where to place it in the layout order. This only really needs to be set when the parent block (in this case, the referenced "left" block) is basically set to `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml(''); ?>`. No arguments in the `('')` means it will load all child blocks in order as the xml defines.

In the case of `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>`, it's calling up the block that has the `name="left"`. After giving it a name, you can alternatively give it another alias by using `as="search.box.alias"` within the `<block />` tag, `search.box.alias` also being anything you want, provided it doesn't cause any conflicts.

Comment: Thank you very much ...it worked like a charm! Thanks for the explanation notes also!